# Windows UWP BluetoothLE Pairing

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

using the nugget package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts and following the code example provided by Microsoft @ [github](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE)

I am able to enumerate the BLE devices and get the exposed GATT services, but any attempt at pairing : `DevicePairingResult result = await info.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.EncryptionAndAuthentication);`
(Tested with all of the possible protection levels) fails.

Form the official documentation no pairing is discussed. It seems that you can get a ble device which windows will automatically connect to and proceed, but my device requires a pin when pairing by hand which confuses me as to how windows could interact with my attributes without providing a pin or even pairing? (not tested).

If anyone has experience with pairing BLE devices to windows via code, any pointer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use CustomPairing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationcustompairing?view=winrt-22000

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thank you! Apparently even supplying the protection level from the device info did not work using the custom pairing, but removing the argument-> boom. PairingRequested event fired!

Comment: Please refer to this  [Device enumeration and pairing sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing)